# Android Wear Location

Tags: java, android, location, wear-os

I am making an Android Wear Watch Face and I need to show user current location.

I was followed tutorial on [Dev site](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/wear-location-detection.html), but I can't get it to work. The code never goes to **"onLocationChanged"** listener.

Device is Huawei watch, and it is connected to mobile with WiFi and Location on.

Permissions are on (I have runtime permission request). Here is the code:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**build.gradle (Module.wear)**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
```

**AnalogFaceService.java**

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(AnalogFaceService.this)
  .addApi(LocationServices.API)
  .addApi(Wearable.API)
  .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
  .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
{
  LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
   .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
   .setInterval(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2))
   .setFastestInterval(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2))
   .setSmallestDisplacement(2);

  if
  (
    (
      ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(AnalogFaceService.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) 
      != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
     ) && (
      ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(AnalogFaceService.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) 
      != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
     )
    ) {
      return;
    }

  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
   .requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, onLocationChangedListener)
   .setResultCallback(locationCallback);
}

private final LocationListener onLocationChangedListener = new LocationListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
  {
    Log.v("LOCATION_TEST", location.getLatitude() + " :::: " + location.getLongitude());
    getSunriseAndSunset(location);

    addLocationEntry(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you post all the code from your activity?

Comment: After hours of checking, rechecking and solution searching, I tried to open Google Maps on the watch to see if location is working at all.
And when it started, my app started working too.
After factory reset, I didn't open Google Maps at all. It is a bit awkward but I guess it works. I will try to revert it to factory settings again and seee what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from Dev site was not a problem.

Device was fresh factory reset and I didn't open *Google Maps* yet so the Watch couldn't get current location and because of that it didn't go into **"onLocationChanged"**.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `connect`.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    googleApiClient.connect();
    ...
}
```

Comment: That was not the problem. GoogleApiClient is connected.